# Video and Audio Drift

Tags: video, audio, audio-recording, video-recording

I was wondering, how much does recorded audio and video drift from their actual recording time usually? (So like, perhaps a frame is dropped or something) I'm recording both separately (into unsigned 8 bit PCM (44100 Hz) and raw image data files) and I was wondering how much I can expect each to drift.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With good hardware and software you can expect no drift at all. Dropped frames are only an artifact of processing lags.

Comment: So you think on playback it should be exactly as it was on recording?

Comment: Assuming fast enough hardware and reliable software, yes - it should be identical.